# How to reformat URLs to be more restful (from .../?id=123 to .../123)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, restful-url

Currently I have pages accessed via:

```
www.foo.com/details.html?id=123
```

I'd like to make them more restful-like, such as by the following:

```
www.foo.com/details/123
```

I'm using Google App Engine.  Currently the URL's are mapped in the `html-mappings` file:

```
 ('/details.html*', DetailsPage),
```

And then on the `DetailsPage` handler, it fetches the `ID` value via:

```
class DetailsPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        announcement_id = self.request.get("id")
```

How might I restructure this so that it can map the URL and a extract the ID via the other-formatted URL: `www.foo.com/details/123`

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rewrite your URL mapping like this:

```
('/details/(\d+)', DetailsPage),
```

(this requires that there be a trailing part of the URL that contains one or more digits and nothing else).

Then modify your `DetailsPage::get()` method to accept that id parameter, like:

```
class DetailsPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, announcement_id):
        # next line no longer needed
        # announcement_id = self.request.get("id")
```

...and carry on with your code.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much!  One change-- I realized I was misleading with the description... what if the id I want to come after /details matches the regex: [a-zA-Z0-9-_]  How can I make reflect this change?  ('/details/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]', DetailsPage), doesn't seem to work (it kept giving me a 404 error).

Comment: for that you can substitute `r"/details/(\w+)"` -- `\w` matches all those characters, the `+` requires that there be at least one matching character, and the parens capture the match into the parameter that's passed to your `get()` function.